# U01 PDF and CDF using SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

Trying to define and get CDF of the U01 PDF, which, in turn, is just a box function

```
from sympy import Function, Symbol, integrate
from sympy.functions.elementary.complexes import sign
```

Ok, defining U01

```
x = Symbol('x')
a = Symbol('a')
w = Symbol('w')
u01 = Function('u01')

u01 = (sign(x) + sign(1-x))/2
```

and output looks ok

[image]

But when trying to integrate PDF

```
integrate(u01,x)
```

I won't get CDF, just

[image]

So, question is, how to get it work

Comment: You need to declare `x` as real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no additional assumptions, `x` is considered to be an arbitrary complex number. In your case you want `x` to be real:

```py
x_real = Symbol('x', real=True)
u01_real = (sign(x_real) + sign(1-x_real))/2
integrate(u01_real,x_real)
```

This outputs

```py
Piecewise((0, x < 0), (x, x < 1), (1, True))
```

See [this](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/assumptions.html) document on assumptions for more details.